# Stop button from moving to line below

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm adding buttons to a site and one of the buttons is moving to the line below, how can i correct this? id like the buttons to be aligned with the sides of the card above but remain on the same line.

[this is how the buttons currently display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNeJb.png)

this is my code:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10 mx-auto">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <button class="btn-dark" (click) ="previousPage()">
                    Previous
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-right">
                <button class="btn-dark" (click) ="nextPage()">
                    Next
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second set of columns need to be a child of a row div, and should not total more than 12 (yours total 14). So make it like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10 mx-auto">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <button class="btn-dark" (click)="previousPage()">Previous</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10 text-right">
          <button class="btn-dark" (click)="nextPage()">Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Codeply example](https://www.codeply.com/p/xDbHZeOX6v)**

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bootstrap 4 or 5 then use flexbox and justify space between your buttons. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/#justify-content

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10 mx-auto d-flex justify-content-between">
            <button class="btn-dark" (click) ="previousPage()">
                Previous
            </button>
            <button class="btn-dark" (click) ="nextPage()">
                Next
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Otherwise @j08691 mentioned already an issue with a missing `row` and incorrect `col` numbers.